# copy from buggy application

Tags: windows, copy-paste

I have an old windows application, which dumps some log-messages in a read-only edit-control.

Due to some weird restriction or a bug, The edit-control does not have a drop-down menu, and the default accelators (Ctrl+c, ctrl+v, ctrl-x, ctrl-f) are disabled.

Since the output is quite large, searching the log manually is quite tedious. I would like to copy the contents of the control to the clipboard (or save it in a file).

Is there an easy way to do this? I am happy to use an external program.

Comment: Can you select the text? Can you right-click on the control? If so, does the right-click menu provide any options to cut or copy?

Comment: I am not allowed to do anything with the text. The edit-control seems to simply drop most input that it receives. I can't select using ctrl-A, nor by mouseclick. The right-click menu does not appear at all.

Comment: What application is it? What does it do?

Comment: I guess the only thing you could do is to take a screenshot of the control box, but again if the log is too large, this will be tedious as well.

Comment: It is a simulator for a project at work (telecom). I am considering downloading a tool like uispy, but is seems overkill.

Comment: if you can select by shift+arrows then try copying with `ctrl+Insert` and pasting with `Shift + Insert`.

Comment: Amazingly enough, ctrl+Insert and shift+insert do indeed work. (I have to correct my last comment, selecting the text by mouseclick works, just not by keyboard). @Yitzchak If you make this an answer, I will accept it, because it is the simplest thing that suits my needs).

Comment: Done, I appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can select at all, then try copying with `ctrl+Insert` and pasting with `Shift + Insert`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use an window info tool like [Au3Info](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/intro/au3spy.htm), this kind of tools allow you to inspect any window and copy its contents.